# AngularJS $resource parameter is not replaced with its real value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have recently decided to use `$resource` for REST service, but I quickly got in trouble. I have a simple URL:

> /r/interface/activate/:active/addr/:address

But calling it in unit test make it fail with:

```
// expected: POST /r/interface/activate/false/addr/123
// got     : POST /r/interface/activate/false/addr/@address
```

My defined resource is :

```
module.factory('NetworkInterfaceActivationService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/r/interface/activate/:active/addr/:address", {}, {
        activate:{method:'POST', params:{active:"true", address:'@address'}, isArray:false},
        deactivate:{method:'POST', params:{active:"false", address:'@address'}, isArray:false}
    });
});
```

And this is how I call my service !

```
$scope.deactivateNetworkAddress = function (address) {
   NetworkInterfaceActivationService.deactivate({address:address});
};
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post a plunker or fiddle so we can play with it? But my gut says you shouln't use '@address' in the params since it's already in the URL. BTW, you shouldn't use actual HTTP methods in your unit tests; you should mock them with ngMockE2E.

Comment: I tried it by simply clicking my form and check network from my browser.

Comment: Like I said, if you can post a plunker or fiddle, I can look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with Angular 1.3, but I couldn't reproduce the problem.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/ehbtv771/)

```
<button ng-click="parentCtrl.doIt('123foobar')">execute</button>
```

```
app.controller('ParentCtrl', function (NetworkInterfaceActivationService) {
    this.doIt = function (address) {
        NetworkInterfaceActivationService.deactivate({address:address});
    };
})

app.factory('NetworkInterfaceActivationService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/r/interface/activate/:active/addr/:address", {}, {
        activate:{method:'POST', params:{active:"true", address:'@address'}, isArray:false}
    });
});
```

HTTP call in console:

> POST .../r/interface/activate/false/addr/123foobar

Comment: I will check it when I have time to work on the project as It is overtime project :P